# Putty login to Ubuntu server using ppk

Tags: server, putty

I would like to login to our Ubuntu server 9 using a PPK from Putty. Is there a simple guide I can follow as I keep getting the message Server refused our key?

This is all setup as someone here can login using this way. But the person that set the system up has left now with no instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [guide](http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/pka-putty.html) to public key authentication with Putty.